# Need Project Priority in Assignment view

Tags: view, project-server, project-online

I am trying to modify an `Assignment view` in Project Online.

I would like to display the `Project Priority` in the **table** portion of the view, but I can only select the `Task Priority`.

How can I display the `Project Priority` as a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of The `assignment views` used to review details about resource assignments and its Tasks not about the project.

So It's logical behavior, to **can't** find the `Project Field` in the fields list at the table portion for these views.

---

By the way, The `Project Priority` field is shown in the related views of the `Project Center` Category like

- Summary.
- Work.
- Cost..... etc

[image]

Comment: I understand your thinking about the levels, but don't other people use the project priority to prioritize between projects, and then task level priority to prioritize within a project?   Therefore, one would want to view the project priority as much or more than the task priority.  Am I the only one that uses project priority this way?

Comment: the project priority to prioritize between projects not available in assignment views!, use other views to do that as i mentioned above!

Comment: Hi @Mark do you still need further clarification? if no Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answers in case it helped you!